# Why is a += b not equivalent to a = a + b here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, append

I was shocked to find out that `a += b` behaves differently from `a = a + b` in my code, and I am able to reduce the issue to the following simple question:

Let's say I have a function `g` that depends on `f` (another function), `x`, `y` and `lst` (a list). Here I provide two versions of `f`, one using `lst = lst + [y]`, the other using `lst += [y]`

```
def f1(x, y, lst=[]):
    lst.append(x)
    lst = lst + [y]
    return lst

def f2(x, y, lst=[]):
    lst.append(x)
    lst += [y]
    return lst

def g(f, x, y, lst=[]):
    return f(x, y, lst) + lst
```

However, I am getting different results:

```
print(g(f1, 1, 2, [3, 4]))
# [3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]

print(g(f2, 1, 2, [3, 4]))
# [3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: In general, beware that `+=` can be overloaded independently of `+`, so there is no reason for `+=` to behave coherently with `+`, besides the developers not doing weird stuff.

Comment: `f1` is creating new `lst` i.e. without referencing to old `lst` where as in `f2`, `lst` is referencing the same `lst` as in place operator is used which mutates the list.

Comment: Also beware of: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of this behavior then use `.copy` function.

```
def f1(x, y, lst):
    lst = lst.copy()
    lst.append(x)
    lst = lst + [y]
    return lst

def f2(x, y, lst):
    lst = lst.copy()
    lst.append(x)
    lst += [y]
    return lst

def g(f, x, y, lst=[]):
    return f(x, y, lst) + lst


print(g(f1, 1, 2, [3, 4]))
# [3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]

print(g(f2, 1, 2, [3, 4]))
# [3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```